# Getting the address for the album art picture for a mp3

Tags: c++, id3lib

I am trying to show the album art picture for a mp3. I am using id3lib and I don't know how to get the info from the tag(I just need the path to the picture). How can I do that?

LATER EDIT

```
const ID3_Frame *frame = tag.Find(ID3FID_PICTURE);
if(frame && frame->Contains(ID3FN_DATA))
{
    cout << "here" << endl;
    frame->Field(ID3FN_DATA).ToFile(pic);

    cout << pic << endl;
}
```

The problem is that at one song the program crash and at other songs, that in media player I see an album art picture, my program never enters in that if. What Could be the problem?

LATER LATER EDIT

Finnaly i've done it. The problem was that i didn't gave the right path to save. But for some pictures works, but for others, altough they have album art pictures, my program doesn't works. Why? How players get their album art picture if the id3 tag doesn't provide it?

Comment: I really need to display that picture. Please somebody can help me to obtain that picture with id3lib?

Answer (score 0):

If you're question is how players get their album art, even if it's not embedded in the ID3 tag. The answer would be: From online sources such as [Gracenote](http://www.gracenote.com/)